# Submit multiple values using only one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

this is a sample what I need:

```
<form action="action.php">
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name1" checked="checked"> First name:name1
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname1">
  <br>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name2"> First name:name2
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname2">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name3"> First name:name3
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname3">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need submit only hidden value where radio is checked. 
For example if I check   `firstname1` i need submit together `firstname1` and hidden `lastname1` only. Can anybody help?

Maybe my question is not correct. When I click submit, I need correspond only one hidden value where radio checked. I can't get it. I have tried some javascript suggested here, but no success.Seems I walking somewhere around. Can anybody show the right way?

Solved.

Comment: Why don't you just let it submit all the inputs. The PHP script can then decide which inputs to use based on the value of `$_POST['firstname']`.

Comment: @Bamar Thanks for suggestion. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("input[type=submit]").on("click",function(e){

         $myRadio = $("input[type=radio]:checked");

         var value1 =$myRadio.val();

         var value2 = $myRadio.nextAll("input[type=hidden]:first").val();

         $.post('action.php', {val:value1,val2:value2 }, function(response) {

             alert(response);

         })

     })

 })
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but this seems does not work. No errors and no action...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to submit a certain part of the form, remove the action from the form and use javascript/AJAX to submit the form instead. Something like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var data = //get the data you want to submit, i think you can figure that part out.

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "js/sendEmail.php", //same link as your action
       data: data,
       success: function(response){
           console.log(response);

       },
       error: function(response){
           console.log(response);

       }
   });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same form, this will happen automatically. All you need to do is pull them correctly.

So in php you would do this;

`$fname = $_POST["firstname1"];`

`$lname = $_POST["lastname1"];`

Answer (score 0):

I would actually just break them into different forms.  The quickest way, and super easy.

```
<form action="action.php" id="form1">
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name_1" checked="checked"> First name:name1
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname1">
</form>

<form action="action.php" id="form2">
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name_2" checked="checked"> First name:name2
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname2">
</form>

<form action="action.php" id="form3">
  <input type="radio" name="firstname" value="name_3" checked="checked"> First name:name3
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="lastname3">
</form>
<input id="submitter" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And in the Javascript, leveraging jQuery:

```
var id = -1;
$("input[name=='firstname']").on("click", function(){
  id = $(this).val().split("_")[1];

}).bind(this);

$("#submitter").on("click", function(){
  if(id==-1) return;
  $("form#form"+id)[0].submit();
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: please describe why, so i could give you more insight?